# Is there a way I can color my ticks in my jqplot graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jqplot

I have a stacked bar graph and I want to color my ticks on my graph.

In the graph below I'd like to color the customers in red or green based on their status:

[image: Bar Graph]

So I would want to color Aava green maybe and Acer red. Is there a way to color each label? I know I'm able to color all of them a color but can I select a specific one?

My first attempts have been to select the label using jquery and apply my own css like this:

```
$("div:contains('Aava')" ).css( "color", "red" );
```

However, this doesn't select anything

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
 $("div.jqplot-xaxis-tick:contains('Aava')").css("color", "red");
```

I'm not sure if it'll work, but it seemed to change the font color of the x labels here:  http://www.jqplot.com/tests/line-charts.php

When I ran:

```
$("div.jqplot-xaxis-tick:contains('2')").css("color", "red");
```

You'll need to be sure this is ran after the DOM is ready and the graph has been created.

Comment: Well that seems to select only some of the xaxis-ticks. If I wanted to select what the chart already renders then this works fine (the numbers that are already pre-defined can be selected). However, since I have added an attribute that labels my x-ticks, I'm not able to select it using "jqplot-xaxis-tick". Do you know why this is? Thanks

Comment: Is there a way you can post an example on jsfiddle?