# Is it possible to apply css to text in a canvas tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, canvas

I have a canvas tag which has come text inside (rendered by a jqplot chart):

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
```

is there a way I can make the text inside the canvas red? I've tried just adding css like this:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200" style="color: red;"></canvas>
```

From what I understand a canvas is almost like an image. Does this mean I wont be able to select things in that canvas?

Comment: Not sure if it suits your use case, but with SVGs you can individually target elements, and style them with CSS (although different rules than apply to HTML). Here is a nice project using semantic SVGs that way: https://useiconic.com/tour/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using `jqplot` you should look at the documentation to figure out how to change the color of the text. The following webpage looks promising which makes mention of a `textColor` property.

http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/plugins/jqplot-canvasAxisLabelRenderer-js.html#$.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer

This looked helpful as well

http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqplot-core-js.html#Axis.tickRenderer

http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqplot-axisTickRenderer-js.html#$.jqplot.AxisTickRenderer

Basically I would try to find an event (hook) that gets called before each tick was drawn. Figure out which tick is about to be drawn. Then change the text color based on that information. I believe you can accomplish that with what I have provided you.

Comment: I did see that at first. However, jqplot is silly and only allows you to color all the ticks on your axis. I want to color each tick a different color. Here's a SO question I posted about it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23304935/is-there-a-way-i-can-color-my-ticks-in-my-jqplot-graph/23305099?noredirect=1#comment35753739_23305099

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with Javascript:

```
<script>
  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  context.font = '40pt Calibri';
  context.fillStyle = 'blue';
</script>
```

## [Source](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-text-color/)

Comment: can you explain what the '2d' is for?

Comment: It means get the 2d drawing context for the given canvas, as opposed to the 3d context.